# How to configure setenv.sh for tomcat8?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

How can I add custom memory parameters to `tomcat8` service?

I created the following file:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  211 Jun 13 10:51 setenv.sh`

Content:

```
#! /bin/sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m"
```

After restart:

`ps aux | grep java`

Result: I cannot see my defined memory options. Only:
`... -Xmx128m`

But why? How can I check if or why setenv.sh is loaded correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Since the question mentions `tomcat8` I assume this refers to the Debian package. I was looking for a Debian-friendly solution to this problem and just discovered another way to add arbitrary system properties to Tomcat on startup.

The standard Debian package for Tomcat also creates a default configuration file under:

`/etc/default/tomcatX` (X is the Tomcat version number).

System properties and other JVM startup parameters can be added to `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
# You may pass JVM startup parameters to Java here. If unset, the default
# options will be: -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
#
# Use "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" to enable the CMS garbage collector (improved
# response time). If you use that option and you run Tomcat on a machine with
# exactly one CPU chip that contains one or two cores, you should also add
# the "-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode" option.
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

This is by the way also the configuration file where a different JVM can be specified, in case multiple are installed on the system, or where the user running Tomcat can be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: I took the wrong directory. setenv.sh must be placed here:

`/usr/share/tomcat8/bin`

Comment: Think setenv.sh shoudl be placed where tomcat is installed i.e. $CATALINA_BASE/bin where $CATALINA_BASE is the path to where tomcat is installed.

Comment: The `/usr/share/` directory should be considered read-only. Check instead `/etc/default/tomcat*`.
Further information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard